# Is there a winning stategy for this NIM-like game : the 17 Dots Challenge?

Tags: game-theory

Today my teacher asked the class if anyone could beat him at a game he (supposedly) invented. The game goes like this: Two players take turns drawing dots on a line on a piece of paper. Whoever gets to draw the 17th point wins the game. You can drow a maximum of 3 dots at a time.
When I heard the rules I immidiatelly thought of NIM, but the strategy seems to be different. Also one thing I noticed is that every game ended with the same kind of moves: There are still 4 dots to be drown, and being player X's turn, he must lose being that whatever he plays, player Y will always have the last turn.
What would the strategy to beat this game be, and why? Is there a generalized strategy for this games and ones similar to this (NIM for example)?

Edit: also he won no matter who started and how

Comment: This is equivalent to the variant of nim, when you have one pile and can remove $1$, $2$ or $3$ coins at any one time. The strategy is to aim to leave a multiple of $4$ coins after your move.

Comment: What are the rules?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've seen that if there are $4$ dots left and it's your turn you lose. It follows by the same argument that if there are $8$ dots left and it's your turn you lose: whatever you do your opponent can play in a way that leaves $4$ dots on your next turn.

Etc. If there are $16$ dots left you lose. So the first player wins by drawing $1$ dot, leaving the opponent with $16$.

Answer (score 0):

The first player has the winning strategy: draw $1$ dot. From then on, whatever the second player plays, the first player just makes the number of dots have the remainder $1$ when divided by $4$ (i.e. $5, 9, 13, 17$).

Comment: He also didn't care who started and with what move, does this affect the game?

Comment: I assumed that would be the case. However, whoever starts first can ensure that they will win. If you start first, draw 1 dot, and then make sure that in the subsequent steps you end up with 5, 9, 13 and finally 17 dots drawn - you win! Try it out against your teacher and let us know what happened (but insist you play first!)

Comment: Ok thank you very much, is there some generalized way to get the 4 in mod 4?

Comment: What I meant that the number of dots after the first player plays must have the remainder 1 when divided by 4. I will update the answer.

Comment: @AchilleMerendino 4 follows from the fact that any player can draw 1,2 or 3 dots - the other player can counter with 3, 2 or 1 dots, respectively so that in those two moves the total number of dots drawn is 4.

Comment: Ok thank you very much 